# How to establish tcp connection between host to vm using ssh or telnet

Tags: ssh, networking, tcp, telnet

As a part of learning, I'm trying to establish a tcp connection between host and VM using telnet or ssh. I'm using linux-debian.
After establishing connection, I'll try to analyse packets using wireshark as a part of learning networking.

But I don't know how to establish a connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You establish a connection with `ssh ACCOUNT@ADDRESS`, where ACCOUNT is a user account on the VM, and ADDRESS is an IP address that allows you to connect with the VM.

The telnet command is `telnet ADDRESS`. You need to launch a telnet server on the VM. The ssh server runs by default on most distros.

If you use KVM and libvirt or virt-manager, by default the VM is attached to a separate network via a bridge. A route to the VM is automatically configured, so that you can just use the VM's IP address.

VirtualBox uses a similar network connection (named NAT) by default, except that you have to set up port forwarding in order to reach the VM and use the configured address+port combination.

There are other methods to attach the VM, and they may require some configuration. I don't know the details how other hypervisors like VMware handle networking.